# Mysql error in Ansible task

Tags: mysql, vagrant

Hello I am running Ansible with Vagrant. But with one of of my Mysql tasks I get the following error

> TASK: [MySQL | Delete anonymous MySQL server user for example.com]
>   ************  fatal: [default] => failed to parse: SUDO-SUCCESS-jqnhqbekvsvfiqwuchtanssqtcwurcxi Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1391947041.93-180495295089354/mysql_user",
>   line 1490, in 
>       main()   File "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1391947041.93-180495295089354/mysql_user",
>   line 401, in main
>       check_implicit_admin=dict(default=False),   File "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1391947041.93-180495295089354/mysql_user",
>   line 648, in **init**
>       (self.params, self.args) = self._load_params()   File "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1391947041.93-180495295089354/mysql_user",
>   line 1191, in _load_params
>       items   = shlex.split(args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
>       return list(lex)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
>       token = self.get_token()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
>       raw = self.read_token()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
>       raise ValueError, "No closing quotation" ValueError: No closing quotation

How could I solve this?

### EDIT

This is the task

> - name: MySQL | Delete anonymous MySQL server user for {{ server_hostname }}
>     action: mysql_user user="" host="{{ server_hostname }} state="absent"
>     tags: common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot closing quotation mark. Here's the correct task:

```
- mysql_user: user="" host="{{ server_hostname }}" state="absent"
  tags: common
```